# Luminosity of the sun

Tags: nuclear-physics, sun, luminosity

How is it that the total power generated by nuclear reaction in the core of Sun exceeds its total luminosity? Where does the difference go?

Comment: Some goes off as neutrinos.

Comment: Whether the neutrinos are the answer or not depends on how you calculated the power generation. Stellar physicists (at least sometimes) use tables for energy of reactions that *exclude* the neutrinos, but if you get your numbers from a general purpose nuclear physics resource, you have to account for the neutrinos yourself.

Comment: It is perhaps interesting to note that the number of [solar neutrinos](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_neutrino) predicted from theory did not match the number of solar neutrinos detected on the Earth and the resolution of the  [solar neutrino problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_neutrino_problem) resulted in the award of Nobel prizes to some of the scientist involved.